# Call script to start another script

Tags: unityscript

I'm putting together a system for Day and Night for my game, I have a script that makes the day goes normally do not put the night, I thought of creating another copy and put the same script for the night and then the first script calls the second and the second calls the first well be an endless cycle of day and night, was wondering if anyone has any ideas to make it better or am new to the programming world so I have no idea how to do this.

Sorry for my english I'm trying to improve, I'm Brazilian. I appreciate all the help and I await response from someone.

```
var slider : float;
var slider2 : float;
var Hour : float;
private var Tod: float;
var sun: Light;


var NightFogColor : Color;
var DuskFogColor : Color;
var MorningFogColor : Color;
var MiddayFogColor : Color;

var NightAmbientLight : Color;
var DuskAmbientLight : Color;
var MorningAmbientLight : Color;
var MiddayAmbientLight : Color;

var NightTint : Color;
var DuskTint : Color;
var MorningTint : Color;
var MiddayTint : Color;

var SkyBoxMaterial1 : Material;
var SkyBoxMaterial2 : Material;

var SunNight : Color;
var SunDay : Color;


function OnGUI () {

slider= GUI.HorizontalSlider( Rect(20,20,200,30), slider, 0,1.0);
Hour= slider*24;
Tod= slider2*24;
sun.transform.localEulerAngles.x= (slider*360)-90;
slider = slider +Time.deltaTime/900;
sun.color = Color.Lerp (SunNight, SunDay, slider*2);
if(slider<0.5){
slider2= slider;
}
if(slider>0.5){
slider2= (1-slider);
}
sun.intensity = (slider2-0.2)*2;


if(Tod<4){
//it is Night
RenderSettings.skybox=SkyBoxMaterial1;
RenderSettings.skybox.SetFloat("_Blend", 0);
SkyBoxMaterial1.SetColor ("_Tint", NightTint);
RenderSettings.ambientLight = NightAmbientLight;
RenderSettings.fogColor = NightFogColor;
}
if(Tod>4&&Tod<6){
RenderSettings.skybox=SkyBoxMaterial1;
RenderSettings.skybox.SetFloat("_Blend", 0);
RenderSettings.skybox.SetFloat("_Blend", (Tod/2)-2);
SkyBoxMaterial1.SetColor ("_Tint", Color.Lerp (NightTint, DuskTint, (Tod/2)-2) );
RenderSettings.ambientLight = Color.Lerp (NightAmbientLight, DuskAmbientLight, (Tod/2)-2);
RenderSettings.fogColor = Color.Lerp (NightFogColor,DuskFogColor, (Tod/2)-2);
//it is Dusk

}
if(Tod>6&&Tod<8){
RenderSettings.skybox=SkyBoxMaterial2;
RenderSettings.skybox.SetFloat("_Blend", 0);
RenderSettings.skybox.SetFloat("_Blend", (Tod/2)-3);
SkyBoxMaterial2.SetColor ("_Tint", Color.Lerp (DuskTint,MorningTint,  (Tod/2)-3) );
RenderSettings.ambientLight = Color.Lerp (DuskAmbientLight, MorningAmbientLight, (Tod/2)-3);
RenderSettings.fogColor = Color.Lerp (DuskFogColor,MorningFogColor, (Tod/2)-3);
//it is Morning

}
if(Tod>8&&Tod<10){
RenderSettings.ambientLight = MiddayAmbientLight;
RenderSettings.skybox=SkyBoxMaterial2;
RenderSettings.skybox.SetFloat("_Blend", 1);
SkyBoxMaterial2.SetColor ("_Tint", Color.Lerp (MorningTint,MiddayTint,  (Tod/2)-4) );
RenderSettings.ambientLight = Color.Lerp (MorningAmbientLight, MiddayAmbientLight, (Tod/2)-4);
RenderSettings.fogColor = Color.Lerp (MorningFogColor,MiddayFogColor, (Tod/2)-4);
}
}
//it is getting Midday
```

Comment: This is not a Javascript. This is `UnityScript`, from game engine `Unity`

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for code to activate and deactivate script you can do it this way.

Assuming both script are in the same object

GetComponent(scriptName).enabled = true; (or false to deactive)